# How use boost tuple to return two vectors

Tags: python, c++, boost

I'm rewriting a python code to C++ and had encountered a problem. I created a function in python:

```
from my_vec import Vector

def param(gamma):

    coeff = Vector(6)
    exp = Vector(6)

    if abs(gamma - 0.3) < 1E-6:
        coeff[0] =  33;   exp[0] =   0.1;
        coeff[1] =  -33;  exp[1] =  2.2;
        coeff[2] =  21;   exp[2] =   0.16;
        coeff[3] =  23;   exp[3] =   3.312;
        coeff[4] =  23;   exp[4] =   100;
        coeff[5] =  32;   exp[5] =  59.00;
    elif abs(gamma - 0.4) < 1E-6:
        coeff[0] =  -0.23;  exp[0] =   0.02;
        coeff[1] =  -0.48;  exp[1] =   0.18;
        coeff[2] =   200;  exp[2] =    1.82;
        coeff[3] =   200;  exp[3] =    3.71;
        coeff[4] =   200;  exp[4] =   14.28;
        coeff[5] =   0.00;  exp[5] =  79.11;

    return coeff, exp
```

Subsequently, I made an attempt to write the same use in C++. It seems that using tuple is what I'm looking for. 
However, I haven't uses it before and I'm struggling with this task.

I created:

```
    std::vector<float> coef1 = {-0.366770, -0.249990, -0.411230, 0.144690, -0.101790, 0.010510};
    std::vector<float> exp1 = {0.02, 1.910630, 0.16492, 3.31721, 10.45634, 59.3438};
    std::vector<float> coef2 = {-0.36, -0.24, -0.41, 0.14, -0.10, 0.01};

    std::vector<float> exp2 = {0.02, 1.23, 12, 3.31, 11, 22};

    typedef boost::tuple<std::vector<float>, std::vector<float>> parameters;
       parameters param1{coef1, exp1};
       parameters param2{coef2, exp2};
```

At this point, I'd love to create conditions like `if abs(gamma - 0.3) < 1E-6` etc end return coeff and exp vectors. How can I create a function like this one written in python?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Updated. Hopefully it makes sense

Comment: What is `gamma` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick translate.¹

There's a subtle point where inclusion of `<cmath>` and using `std::abs` is essential to get the floating point version of `abs`.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8de5b3f8c537ead1)</kbd>**

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using vec6 = std::array<double, 6>;
using params = std::tuple<vec6, vec6>;

params param(double gamma) {
    using std::abs; // enable ADL in case you use e.g. boost::multiprecision as the vector element type
    if (abs(gamma - 0.3) < 1E-6) {
        return std::make_tuple ( 
                vec6{{-0.366770, -0.249990, -0.411230, 0.144690, -0.101790, 0.010510}}, // coeff1
                vec6{{0.02, 1.910630, 0.16492, 3.31721, 10.45634, 59.3438}} ); // exp1
    }
    if (abs(gamma - 0.4) < 1E-6) {
        return std::make_tuple ( 
                vec6{{-0.36, -0.24, -0.41, 0.14, -0.10, 0.01}}, // coeff2
                vec6{{0.02, 1.23, 12, 3.31, 11, 22}} ); // exp2
    }

    throw std::runtime_error("unhandled gamma");
}

int main() {
    auto p = param(0.4);
}
```

¹ using the values from the tentative C++ version, not the python version

Comment: Thank you very much! It helps a lot. However, I have one more question. I have unpack my parameters (coeff and exp). Could you give me a hint how to do it, please? I've tired to use tie and get, but with no luck.

Comment: The `tie` approach. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8479d1796c37ebc
The `get` approach. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/283ca17d521a292a

Comment: cppreference.com has excellent samples http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie or http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get

Comment: Thank you very much, sehe! I've learned a lot thanks to your answers and explanations. I see how C++ is so powerful!